# Is one allowed to work with the studienkolleg student applicant visa?

Tags: germany

So I recently got the student applicant visa, and after writing the exams I have, and I get accepted, there maybe a buffer period of a few months before my studies start. My question is can I work during this time?

Comment: If your visa has a note "Erwerbstätigkeit gestattet", than yes. Otherwise, you need to ask at Ausländerbehörde for a work permit (students are usually allowed to work 240 half days or 120 full days per year).